# Changing color of checkbox label when checked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am trying to change the color of my checkbox's label when it is checked. I've done this before on other sites, but for some reason my code just isn't working on this one. I am using Drupal 7 with bootstrap 3+.

My checkbox looks like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input class="onlinecheckbox" type="checkbox" name="dealtype[]" id="prov1" onchange="this.form.submit()" value="booking" checked="">
    <label for="prov1">Booking</label>
</div>
```

My css is as follows:

```
.onlinecheckbox input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.onlinecheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    color: #428bca;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should place `.onlinecheckbox` after `input[type="checkbox"]`:

```css
input[type="checkbox"].onlinecheckbox + label {
    color: #ffffff;
}

input[type="checkbox"].onlinecheckbox:checked + label {
    color: #428bca;
}
```

Comment: The selectors in the question are *valid*, they are just not *right* (do not match the elements they are meant to match).

Answer (score 0):

try it works

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<style>
input[type="checkbox"] +label {
    color: #ffffff;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    color: #428bca;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input class="onlinecheckbox" type="checkbox" name="dealtype[]" id="prov1" onchange="this.form.submit()" value="booking" checked="">
    <label for="prov1">Booking</label>
</div>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```