# How can I change the color of Bootstrap checkbox?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <form name="queryForm" class="form-inline text-center">
    <p class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOther" value="other" ng-model="formData.other" ng-true-value="'other'" ng-init="formData.other='other'">Other</p>
   </form>
 </div>
```

and the result of that is:

[image]

What's the simplest way of changing this color to a given one, for example D7B1D7?

Comment: Mate, this is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768623/how-do-you-change-the-style-of-a-bootstrap-checkbox and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821895/changing-color-of-checkbox-label-when-checked Hope you get it working.

Comment: Your HTML code linked to bootstrap CSS doesn't reproduce  the result you show. Do you use some  plugin or is there some HTML (with bootstrap class missing ? because one way is http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MeWemd

Comment: Did my answer help? If not, feel free to ask any questions. I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: I've updated my fiddle. Please see the comments in my answer. I've updated the original link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've adapted the `.squaredThree` class from this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm) for your example. There's a Fiddle link at the bottom of my answer if you want to see a live example.

Here's the updated CSS:

```
/* .squaredThree */
.squaredThree {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}

.squaredThree label {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #D7B1D7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.squaredThree label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* end .squaredThree */
```

I've updated your HTML to include another `label`, as the original `label` is used as a pseudo checkbox. This is your updated HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form name="queryForm" class="form-inline">
    <div class="squaredThree">
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOther" value="other" ng-model="formData.other" ng-true-value="'other'" ng-init="formData.other='other'">
      <label for="checkOther"></label>
    </div>
    <label class="label-text">Other</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note that the additional `label` exists outside the `.squaredThree` `div`. The `label` has a class of `.label-text` as some additional styling rules are needed to move the text slightly to the right of the `checkbox`:

```
.label-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Finally, the size of the check in the `checkbox` isn't quite right so an additional rule is needed to rectify that:

```
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: initial;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/3pgnwLtL/) showing the above in action.

Comment: thank you very much, I viewed your fiddle and it works great, I just have one more question - is there a way of updating the html code so that I have 3 checkboxes next to each other? What I want to achieve is this http://imgur.com/6onY6GA and I thought it should be enough to copy the html code three times, but this is the result https://jsfiddle.net/pvyp4mL3/3/ what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you wrap each checkbox with a class of `.container` it fixes the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/pvyp4mL3/

Comment: Thank you @Yass!! So is there a way of putting those checkboxes and their labels next to each other instead of one above each other? :)

Comment: @user3766930 Do you mean like this? https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/pvyp4mL3/5/

Answer (score 29):

If you use bootstrap and you need to change checkbox background color, just override these styles:

```css
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: green!important;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25)
}
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:active ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: #C8FFC8; 
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <div class="myTest custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1" />
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me, to change the background-color of a checkbox from react-bootstrap. Put this in your css:

```
input[type=checkbox]{
    accent-color: green;
}
```

Comment: React, angular or plain Bootstrap - this works!

Answer (score 4):

```
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
  border-color: #D7B1D7;
  background-color: #D7B1D7;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap default styles:

```.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: #007bff;
} ```

Just overriding that

Answer (score 4):

For Bootstrap 4, the answer of @AndrewRIGHT is fine ([How can I change the color of Bootstrap checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493852/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-bootstrap-checkbox/54113824#54113824)). However, if you use Boostrap 5, the following styles are needed.

```css
.form-check-input:checked{
   background-color: green !important;
   border: 0;
}
.form-check-input:focus, .label::after, label.form-check-label:focus, .form-check-input::after, .form-check-input:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus {
   color: black;
   outline: 0;
   border: 0;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.1rem green !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
Default checkbox
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckChecked">
Checked checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple version of AndrewRIGHT's answer:

```
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    background-color: #333;
    border-color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`input[type=checkbox]` does not not have a `background-color` property. You can use other ways to get your desirable result:

1. You can use the checkbox inside a div and then style the div according to your needs.

   ```
   <div class="row">
     <input type="checkbox" />
   </div>
   ```
2. You can use pseudo elements like these:

   ```
     input[type=checkbox] {
        cursor: pointer;
     }

    input[type=checkbox]:after {
     content: " ";
     background-color: #D7B1D7;
     display: inline-block;
     visibility: visible;
    }

    input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
      content: "\2714";
    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your 2nd method and this is what I got: http://imgur.com/uS3J5ou it does not look exactly how I would like it to look... Could you show me some example of the first point?

Comment: Can you send an image/snapshot/link of how would like it to look?

Comment: @Mona so I want to achieve an effect similar to the one I have already: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P27OU.png but instead of blue I would like to have a different color (in my case - orange)

Answer (score 1):

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked{
    background-color: #028DD2 !important;
}
```

this worked for me. Background color changes whenever you click on the checkbox, then changes back when you click it again.

Comment: In Bootstrap 5.3 this works for me too, even without !important.