# Bootstrap checkbox checked color is green in firefox android but blue anywhere else

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form as below. When I check the checkbox, the color turns to blue except in android Firefox. I am not able to check it out in development mode. `Bootstrap Version 4.4.1`

I have no idea where the problem lies.

```css
.form-control-check-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.form-control-check {
  /* 
  width: 70px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: 10px; 
  */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-control-check {
    /*
    width: 80px;
    margin-top: -13px; 
    */
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group mb-5">
      <div class="form-control-check-container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control form-control-check" name="termsCheckbox" id="termsCheckbox">
        <label for="termsCheckbox">
          I have read terms and conditions
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to not set hard widths and use other heavy-handed custom styles with Bootstrap. There are probably better ways. Also, `col-12 and col-md-12` is redundant. You only need the first class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the color of Bootstrap checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37493852/1264804)